# How to modify this object in "extension" method?

Tags: javascript, extension-methods

I would like to add `splice` method to String which behaves exactly like `splice` method for Array. The problem is `splice` modifies "this" object and returns removed elements. No problem with the latter, but how to write that "this" is modified?

```
if (typeof String.prototype.splice != 'function') {
    String.prototype.splice = function (index,count,add) {
        var removed = this.slice(index,index+count);
        this = this.slice(0, index) + (add || '') + this.slice(index + count); // (*)
        return removed;
  };
}
```

I cannot write it like this. So how to modify "this" object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible - except within a constructor it's not possible to assign to `this`, and the `String` type provides no functions that modify a string in-place.

Comment: Shortly, String type is immutable.

Comment: @Oday whilst that's the implicit effect of the above, it's unclear whether that's a formal requirement of the language.  The MDN site makes no mention of it, nor can I find anything in the ES5 specification.

Comment: It is mentioned in the MDN at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type

Comment: @Oday thanks - it didn't appear on the main reference page for `String`.